# Android - How to package documents into an app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, pdf, sdk

I'm trying to create an app and have the ability to save files to /data/data/(packagename)/files or a directory similar to that.  The goal would be to have a pdf or doc handler, as necessary, open the files stored on the internal storage and be viewed by the user.  I have the code to get a pdf reader that is installed and display the file but I do not know how to package the files so they are installed in a directory like the one above.  Also, if I am able to do this would I use getResources to access the files?  How should the file structure look in eclipse to make this happen on install of the APK?

I do prefer to have the files stored internally (they are small) and not on the SD card.

I admit I am new to this and am trying to learn as I go.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your approach you only need to place your files to assets folder of your application and then just copy them to the internal storage. Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html).

Comment: So, I add all the files in the assets folder, they get put where on installation?  I tried looking in the DDMS perspective but did not find my test pdf file.  Also, unless the file is on the SD card I cannot open it from whereever it is once it is placed in assets.  Would I use AssetManager for this?